# Cubing in the year 2024

Tags: riddle, mathematics, rubiks-cube

Why do Rubik's Cube fans love the year 2024?

Happy New Year everyone!

Comment: 50th anniversary?

Comment: There is a mathematical reason

Comment: Is this [knowledge]?

Comment: I don't think it's knowledge. Not common anyway

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you

> take 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 etc… all the way to 9^3 you get 2024.

Therefore

> they would like it because 2024 you could say from a certain perspective is entirely composed of **many cubes, each one being unique** like the way a Rubik’s cube more or less is (the uniqueness here for each is due to the different combination of colorings of the cube’s faces)!!

Comment: You are on the right track. The intended answer has more cubing :)

Comment: What about now??

Comment: Rubik's cubes aren't entirely composed of cubes, though :-)

Comment: yes you got it now!